# Create table in AWS Redshift via redshift-data api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift cluster created via terraform. When  the cluster is up a lambda function gets invoked in which I am trying to create table in Redshift via redshift-data api. The code doesn't throw any error and there are no errors in cloudwatch logs however I cannot see the table in the database.

The role attached to lambda function has following permissions so I assume that it has the privileges to execute the query

```
"redshift-data:ExecuteStatement",
"redshift-data:CancelStatement",
"redshift-data:ListStatements",
"redshift-data:GetStatementResult",
"redshift-data:DescribeStatement",
"redshift-data:ListDatabases",
"redshift-data:ListSchemas",
"redshift-data:ListTables",
"redshift-data:DescribeTable"
```

Below is the code in the lambda function.

```
import json
import boto3

EVENT_TYPE = "REDSHIFT-EVENT-2000"


def hello(event=None, context=None):
    print(event)
    if event is not None:
        message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
        print(message)
        if message is not None and EVENT_TYPE in message:
            # convert the str to python dictionary
            message_dict = json.loads(message)
            print(message)
            # get the cluster details
            cluster_name = message_dict.get('Resource', None)
            print(cluster_name)
            if cluster_name is not None:
                client_red = boto3.client('redshift',region_name = 'us-east-2')
                clusters = client_red.describe_clusters(ClusterIdentifier=cluster_name)
                cluster_detail = clusters.get('Clusters')[0]
                print(cluster_detail)
                db_name = cluster_detail.get('DBName')
                user_name = cluster_detail.get('MasterUsername')
                db_endpoint = cluster_detail.get('Endpoint')
                print(db_endpoint)
                db_address = db_endpoint.get('Address')
                db_port = db_endpoint.get('Port')

                print(db_name)
                print(db_address)
                print(db_port)
                print(user_name)

                client_data = boto3.client('redshift-data' , region_name = 'us-east-2')

                response = client_data.execute_statement(
                    ClusterIdentifier = cluster_name,
                    Database = db_name,
                    DbUser = user_name,
                    Sql = 'CREATE TABLE TEST (key LONG);'
                )

                print(response)
```

Could someone please help me as I am not able to figure out what exactly the issue is.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you need to COMMIT the actions.  Add COMMIT; to your SQL.

If not you can look at stl_query to see if the query ran or if it isn't being launched.

Comment: I'm not able execute SELECT query itself. The scenario is same as above.

Comment: Why do you say "I'm not able execute SELECT query itself"?  Are you now seeing an error?  The code above just has a CREATE TABLE statement, where is the select coming from?  Are you selecting from the table after the create and not seeing it?  Have you checked the statement text log file and not seen the CREATE statement?  A COMMIT is like a "publish" action and makes changes to the database permanent.